# Stop: Unknown instance mongodb (Ubuntu)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, service, restart

I am new to Mongodb. When I run the following command:

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

It shows me **"mongodb start/running, process 3566"**. But when I try to stop by giving the below command:

```
sudo service mongodb stop
```

It shows **stop: Unknown instance:**. Do anybody have any idea how to slove this issue.

And if I give **sudo service mongodb restart**, I'm getting the below message:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
mongodb start/running, process 3644
```

PS: If I'm using just **mongod**, I could start the server and could connect the mongo shell by giving **mongo**.

Please suggest me how to fix the issue and how to connect mongo shell after giving **service mongodb start**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like this has been answered here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072563/cannot-restart-mongodb-on-ubuntu-11-04

Comment: Thanks. But I don't find the log file in log directory /var/log/mongodb/.

Answer (score 16):

I just ran into this.
Chances are the issue is in your conf file (obviously, since you reinstalled the seeded)

In the mongodb.conf do not set fork = true if calling it as a service. This will prevent the service call from being able to access it with service mongodb.conf status/stop/restart.

Removing a fork=True line, however, will alleviate the issue.

See comments; use the other solution even though this one is accepted.

Comment: Thanks @goingtharn: we spent a few hours trying to solve this, and this did the trick.

Comment: @AlexP. Why is that solution the proper solution (check jonatan's comment on that solution)? You could update your solution to clarify.

Comment: Removing fork when is run as a service finally solved my problem, i expent days on this...

Answer (score 12):

The reason you get the `Unknown instance` error is because `upstart` is tracking the wrong `PID` for the instance of forked `mongod` process. But the proper solution to this is not running the process in foreground by removing `fork=true` line from the config like @GoingTharn suggesting, but rather helping `upstart` to capture the right `PID` of the forked process by adding

```
expect daemon
```

to the `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm on ubuntu 12.04:

Comment: Please, can you make more detail ? maybe copy correct the mongodb.conf file because i dont exp with mongo and cannot understand expect deamon :(

Comment: Why is disabling fork not a proper solution? The [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--fork) states that you should run mongodb as a daemon "either by using --fork or by using a controlling process that handles the daemonization process (e.g. as with upstart and systemd)"

Answer (score 2):

I faced exactly the same problem and did the followings:

- Removed the file mongod.lock (in my case this file was located at /var/lib/mongodb/)
- Used the following command from my mongo client

> mongo --repair

And that fixed the issue. It may be noted that I had a system crash prior to this problem appeared. Therefore, what I believe, the problem was caused due to the unclean shutdown of the server demon.

If you are unsure of the reason, you may wish to have a look at the log file (in my case I found it under /var/log/mongodb/). That might give you some useful hints.

Thanks.

Comment: Error parsing command line: unknown option repair
try 'mongo --help' for more information

Answer (score 2):

I faced it as you had.Maybe it is because my computer crash unexpectedly.I use the command: `sudo top`(ubuntu), and I found mongo running.I killed it and start mongo.Every thing turns right.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by myself. Below is what I did:

```
 apt-get install mongodb
```

And overwrote .conf file. After that everything works fine. I hope this would help someone.

Comment: I don't think reinstalling mongodb as a solution.