# MongoDB wont start after clean Linux install

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, terminal, installation

I have a problem with my MongoDB installation on Linux. I just need to install MongoDB local. 
I started with a outdated version (2.4.9), so I used these command lines to delete the entire old version:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

So at this moment I had no version of MongoDB installed on my Linux Mint Qaina 17

I went to the website: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
Did the following command lines, just like the websites told me to do:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo service mongod start
```

At this moment I have MongoDB 2.6.5 installed. The latest version.
After I got none error, I restart my terminal. 
This is my result in terminal after I typed: sudo mongod

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-10-31T19:24:30.653+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2749 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=XXX-pc
2014-10-31T19:24:30.653+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
2014-10-31T19:24:30.653+0100 [initandlisten] git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
2014-10-31T19:24:30.653+0100 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build8.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-10-31T19:24:30.653+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-10-31T19:24:30.654+0100 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-10-31T19:24:30.728+0100 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-10-31T19:24:30.729+0100 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-10-31T19:24:30.894+0100 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2014-10-31T19:24:30.894+0100 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
2014-10-31T19:24:30.895+0100 [initandlisten] now exiting
2014-10-31T19:24:30.895+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-10-31T19:24:30.896+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.896+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.896+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.896+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.896+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.896+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.969+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.970+0100 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-10-31T19:24:30.970+0100 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2014-10-31T19:24:30.970+0100 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2014-10-31T19:24:31.028+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-10-31T19:24:31.029+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Could anybody tell me what the problem is? I had the same problem on a

Comment: Is mongod already running? This error states that port 27017 is already in use by another process. I would run a ps -ef | grep mongo to double check that mongo isn't already up. If it isn't you could also change the port # with a --port argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 2014-10-31T19:24:30.894+0100 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind()
> failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
>
> 2014-10-31T19:24:30.894+0100 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in
> use 2014-10-31T19:24:30.895+0100 [initandlisten] now exiting

means that some process is already bound to port 27017.

You can find out which one with `lsof -i :27017` (running with superuser priviledge, with `sudo` for instance)

It is probably the `mongod` service installed (and started) with the mongod package.

You can verify this with `sudo service mongod status`

Comment: Just partially true. The status check fails on newer Ubuntu and other Debianish systems as of a problem with reading the pid. A `ps ax | grep [m]ongod` does the same more reliable, without sudo. On the other hand, it is wrong to assume that everybody needs to use `sudo` for each command. Some people actually administer even their Ubuntu system as root, and contrary to what the "canonical" fairytal tellers try to establish, there is nothing evil about that. When changing your ID, you know you have to be careful. When suggesting doing sth via sudo, you should warn about it's power and explain.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, even if some people administer their system as root, giving them command with sudo is not wrong. I'll edit my answer to take into account your comment.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, service mongod status is the canonical command to check the status of a service. Overwhelming new users with possible bug and their workaround would not help them imho.

Comment: I suggest you install MongoDB on a fresh ubuntu system and try to stop it with `service mongod stop`. And have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303685/stop-unknown-instance-mongodb-ubuntu. ;)

Comment: as I said, I don't want to overwhelm users with a bug that is transient (question is not specific to a ubuntu version, the answer shoudl not be)

Comment: A) If you read the question closely, the problem _is_ specific to Ubuntu -at least the Ubuntu packages provided by the 10gen repo. And guess what, they install the same upstart script regardless of which ubuntu derivate they are installed on. B) The OP needs help _now_. If he or she could wait until that bug in the startup scripts is fixed, he or she would not have asked. C) If you wanted it to make general and for the future, you should have used systemd commands instead of upstart.

Comment: ok, let's avoid extending this discussion since the OP already found the answer useful a few hours ago. anyway thanks for your detail and specific precision around this packaging issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response!

Result:

```
sudo lsof -i :27017
[sudo] password for XXX: 
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mongod  1294 mongodb    8u  IPv4  11020      0t0  TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
```

and

```
sudo service mongod status
mongod start/running, process 1294
```

When I go to my webbrowser and type

`http://localhost:27017/mydb`

I get a **"It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."** Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's working. Through a GUI I can enter my local database Thanks everyone!

Comment: great! for your next question, try to post results as comment instead of posting a new response

Comment: Sure, will do. I am new here, so I will pay attention to it next time.
I am not sure if this is allowed, but could you take a look at this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690170/mongodb-on-server-installed-connections0?noredirect=1#comment41977277_26690170

I need to prep a MongoDB ubuntu server, but I have some problems