# MongoDB on server installed, connections:0

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

We need to prepare a ubuntu-server with MongoDB.
We managed to install it properly. When we type:

```
sudo mongod
```

this is our result:

```
XXX@ubuntu-vm:~$ sudo mongod
[sudo] password for XXX: 
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-11-01T14:42:19.717+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15519 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ubuntu-vm
2014-11-01T14:42:19.718+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
2014-11-01T14:42:19.718+0100 [initandlisten] git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
2014-11-01T14:42:19.718+0100 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build8.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-11-01T14:42:19.718+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-11-01T14:42:19.718+0100 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-11-01T14:42:19.732+0100 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-11-01T14:42:19.733+0100 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-11-01T14:42:19.745+0100 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-11-01T14:43:19.755+0100 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:35 virt:344
2014-11-01T14:43:19.755+0100 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-11-01T14:43:19.756+0100 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

After that, nothing happens. I keeps saying:

```
2014-11-01T14:48:19.770+0100 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:35 virt:344
2014-11-01T14:48:19.770+0100 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-11-01T14:48:19.770+0100 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

Could anybody tell us what is happening here? We just need MongoDB installed. We have a admin account with all rights. We need make sure we can start the MongoDB server and manage it through a GUI.

When we type: mongo
Result:

```
2014-11-01T15:30:22.616+0100 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Another try:

```
XXX@ubuntu-vm:~$ sudo service mongod start
[sudo] password for XXX: 
mongod start/running, process 15671

XXX@ubuntu-vm:~$ sudo mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-11-01T15:33:10.025+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15677 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ubuntu-vm
2014-11-01T15:33:10.026+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
2014-11-01T15:33:10.026+0100 [initandlisten] git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
2014-11-01T15:33:10.027+0100 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build8.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-11-01T15:33:10.027+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-11-01T15:33:10.027+0100 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-11-01T15:33:10.041+0100 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-11-01T15:33:10.041+0100 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-11-01T15:33:10.062+0100 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-11-01T15:34:10.057+0100 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:35 virt:344
2014-11-01T15:34:10.058+0100 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-11-01T15:34:10.058+0100 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

Thanks in advance. We appreciate any comment/answer.

Comment: Your "second try" actually started `mongod` twice (once as a service and once directly on the command line).

Comment: When I launch the GUI Robomongo and use 127.0.0.1:27017, it says the connection is good, only the authorization failed. But I am 100% sure I have the right login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB installed correctly. What you need to do is configure it (edit `/etc/mongodb.conf`) enable the service (`sudo service mongod start`).

Both of which, you will note, are clearly documented (as well as everything else you need to do to get MongoDB up and running on a Ubuntu machine) at the very first link Google returns when you search for "ubuntu mongodb install": http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

As for the "0 connections" thing, it simply means that nobody is connecting to your database server (which makes perfect sense given that you're in the process of setting it up -- your production applications that use MongoDB shouldn't be started until the DB server is up and running).