# Mongodb not create the process [Ubuntu machine]

Tags: mongodb

I created a **Ubuntu** machine on a koding.com environment (like AWS EC2 Ubuntu).
That environment comes with a **Mongodb 2.6** preinstalled but i need **Mongo 3.0** at least, I uninstalled the **2.6** and installed the **3.2**. This is What happens when i try to stop the service.

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
myUser: ~/Web/project $
```

Before stop the service i started, this is what i found:

```
myUser: ~/Web/project $ sudo service mongod start
mongod start/running, process 5538
```

Also, i searched here [Stop: Unknown instance mongodb (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303685/stop-unknown-instance-mongodb-ubuntu/21354762#21354762) without help.

Comment: How did you uninstall 2.6? How did you install 3.2?

Comment: I used sudo apt-get purge mongo* + autoremove also, and then just follow the manual from the MongoDB website for the community edition on ubuntu.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Remove files from:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Then:

1. `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list`
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`