# Cannot start mongodb back up stop: Unknown instance:

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

So I am trying to restart mongodb 3.2 and enable authorization, so i edit the /etc/mongod.conf file  and added

```
security:
    authorization:enabled
```

then i saved the file, and typed in

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

which showed that it restarted correctly, but when I looked at the processes running, mongod is not one of them.
And now I cant restart it at all.

Also, there was already a database with information in monogodb before i enabled authorization. Im not sure if that is important to know.

I checked out the solutions in here [Stop: Unknown instance mongodb (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303685/stop-unknown-instance-mongodb-ubuntu)

but i dont have a " fork = true" statement anywhere in /etc/mongod.conf

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so strange enough, I did the following
1) went back to the /etc/mongod.conf file and commented out the authorization configuration.
2) typed in   `sudo service mongod start` and gave me back the the job is already running.
3) checked the the running processes and mongodb was now running properly! I even accessed it through the monoShell
4) then i stopped the service `sudo service mongod stop`
5) I went back and add the following exact syntax

```
security    
   authorization: enabled
```

6) saved the file and `sudo service mongod start`

and waaar'yaaa know. its working.....
can someone explain ? that would be helpful